# Symfony 2 Form Errors

Tags: php, oop, symfony, twig

i want to have a simple

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

call in twig for all my validation errors.

But this is not working. 
Only when i call a field specifically i get the validation message back, but only for this field.

Is it possible to return all my validation messages in one simple {{ form_errors(form) }} call ?

example of my entity validation :

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pdb_domain_account", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 * message = "The field name cannot be empty")
 * @Assert\Regex("/^[A-z]+$/",
 * message = "Only letters are allowed for the relation name.")
 */
private $pdbDomainAccount;
```

this is working for one field :

```
{{ form_errors(form.pdbDomainAccount) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your form types are setting `error-bubbling` to `true`, so they pass the errors to the parent form, and then you can use `{{ form_errors(form) }}`

*From Symfony2 doc:*

> If true, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field
>   or form. For example, if set to true on a normal field, any errors for
>   that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific
>   field.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling